# segmentation fault on vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a piece of code which uses the DFS algorithm for solving the subset problem in Leetcode. The problem is stated as below.

Given a set of distinct integers, S, return all possible subsets.

Note: Elements in a subset must be in non-descending order. The solution set must not contain duplicate subsets.

For example, If S = [1,2,3], a solution is: [ [3], [1], [2], [1,2,3], [1,3], [2,3], [1,2], [] ]

my c++ code is as below, the problem is that it outputs "=======", but after that it says "segmentation fault". I don't really get this segmentation fault error. Can someone tell me which part of the code is wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){

class Solution
{
public:
    //Solution();
    //~Solution();
    std::vector< std::vector<int>  > subset(std::vector<int> S){
        sort(S.begin(), S.end());
        std::vector< std::vector<int> > res;
        std::vector<int> temp;
        res.push_back(temp);
        dfs(res, temp, S, 0);

        return res;
    }

private:
    void dfs(std::vector<std::vector<int> > res, std::vector<int> temp,     std::vector<int> S, int pos){
        for (int i = pos; i <= S.size()-1; i++)
        {
        temp.push_back(S[i]);
        res.push_back(temp);
        dfs(res, temp, S, i+1);
        temp.pop_back();                    /* code */
        }
    }

        /* data */
    };


std::vector<int> array(3);
array[0]=1; array[1]=2; array[2]=3;
std::vector<std::vector<int> > res;
Solution MySolution;
res=MySolution.subset(array);

cout<<"======="<<endl;
cout<<res[0][0]<<endl;

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: just use `oid dfs(std::vector<std::vector<int> >& res, std::vector<int>& temp,     std::vector<int>& S, int pos)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing copies of vectors, not vector references.

```
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > res;
    std::vector<int> temp;
    res.push_back(temp);
    dfs(res, temp, S, 0);
```

This code creates a `vector<vector<int>> res;`, pushes an empty vector to it, then calls a function that does not change any state within this scope.  Finally, you then de-reference with `res[0][0]`.  `res[0]` gives an empty vector, so then the second `[0]` segfaults.

Replace this function definition:

```
void dfs(std::vector<std::vector<int>> res, std::vector<int> temp, std::vector<int> S, int pos){...}
```

With this:

```
void dfs(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& res, std::vector<int>& temp, const std::vector<int>& S, int pos){...}
```

Comment: Hi, I think the vector is passed by reference by default, isn't it? I did the change according to your suggestion, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: No, nothing in C++ is pass by reference by default; this is an artifact from C.  It will always pass sliced copies.  Does it crash somewhere else, or the same spot?

Comment: yes, the same spot. It outputs "=======" and then says "Segmentation fault".

Comment: Hi, I found the problem. It is at `std::vector<int> temp;
        res.push_back(temp);` `temp` is an empty vector right now, so pushing back an empty vector into `res` is causing segmentation fault.

Comment: Yea, you are still pushing an empty vector.  Just get rid of that initial push in `subset()`.

Comment: yeah, you are right. Thanks. Also that it should be `for (int i = pos; i <= S.size()-1; i++)` instead of `for (int i = pos; i <= S.size()-2; i++)`, otherwise it doesn't give the right result.

Answer (score 1):

`dfs(res, temp, S, i+1);`, is almost certainly the source of your problem. On the last iteration, `i+1 == S.size()` resulting in a segmentation fault. An easy fix is:

```
for (int i = pos; i <= S.size()-2; i++)
```

Comment: If `pos == S.size()`, won't it fail the `i = pos; i<=S.size()-1;` check, seeing as it is now greater than the test value?

Comment: @awesomeyi, if you are right, it should have segmentation fault at `res=MySolution.subset(array);`, right? why it outputs "========" and only complain whey I request res[0][0]? I changed to `S.size()-2`, it still gives me the same error.